# elasticsearch mongodb river doesnt index

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

i am using mongodb 3.0.0, elasticsearch 1.4.2 with elasticsearch mapper 2.4.3 and mongodb river 2.0.6

i have made river settings, mongodb opened connection for elasticsearch and elasticsearch try to import data. however no data imported. here is elasticsearch start log, what should be the problem?

```
{
"took": 9,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "_river",
            "_type": "mongodb",
            "_id": "_meta",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "type": "mongodb",
                "mongodb": {
                    "servers": [
                        {
                            "host": "127.0.0.1",
                            "port": 27017
                        }
                    ],
                    "options": {
                        "secondary_read_preference": true
                    },
                    "db": "test",
                    "collection": "users",
                    "gridfs": true
                },
                "index": {
                    "name": "mongotest",
                    "type": "users"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "_river",
            "_type": "mongodb",
            "_id": "_riverstatus",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "mongodb": {
                    "status": "RUNNING"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "_river",
            "_type": "mongodb",
            "_id": "_status",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "node": {
                    "id": "L7_mQH1OQ-GaO4nmUMeUEg",
                    "name": "Wundarr the Aquarian",
                    "transport_address": "inet[/192.168.1.249:9300]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

logs ;

```
[2015-03-23 11:18:07,031][INFO ][river.mongodb.util ] setRiverStatus called with mongodb - STOPPED
[2015-03-23 11:18:07,157][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.StatusChecker] About to stop river: mongodb
[2015-03-23 11:18:07,158][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Stopping river mongodb
[2015-03-23 11:18:07,159][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Stopped river mongodb
[2015-03-23 11:18:07,159][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Indexer] river-mongodb indexer interrupted
[2015-03-23 11:18:09,692][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.OplogSlurper] river-mongodb slurper interrupted
[2015-03-23 11:18:09,693][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.OplogSlurper] Slurper is stopping. River has status STOPPED
```

this is also elasticsearch start log;

```
[2015-03-23 11:16:56,582][INFO ][node ] [Sean Cassidy] version[1.4.2], pid[5576], build[927caff/2014-12-16T14:11:12Z]
[2015-03-23 11:16:56,583][INFO ][node ] [Sean Cassidy] initializing ...
[2015-03-23 11:16:56,716][INFO ][plugins ] [Sean Cassidy] loaded [mongodb-river, mapper-attachments], sites [river-mongodb]
[2015-03-23 11:17:01,854][INFO ][node ] [Sean Cassidy] initialized
[2015-03-23 11:17:01,855][INFO ][node ] [Sean Cassidy] starting ...
[2015-03-23 11:17:04,825][INFO ][transport ] [Sean Cassidy] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.1.249:9300]}
[2015-03-23 11:17:10,131][INFO ][discovery ] [Sean Cassidy] elasticsearch/0p1Uz_ZNTB-ZBS5EXeRsCQ
[2015-03-23 11:17:13,923][INFO ][cluster.service ] [Sean Cassidy] new_master [Sean Cassidy][0p1Uz_ZNTB-ZBS5EXeRsCQ][MTRCW077][inet[/192.168.1.249:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-03-23 11:17:15,046][INFO ][http ] [Sean Cassidy] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.1.249:9200]}
[2015-03-23 11:17:15,047][INFO ][node ] [Sean Cassidy] started
[2015-03-23 11:17:15,430][INFO ][gateway ] [Sean Cassidy] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
[2015-03-23 11:17:16,085][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.6] - hash[3c38a8a] - time[2015-03-10T03:06:51Z]
[2015-03-23 11:17:16,090][INFO ][river.mongodb.util ] setRiverStatus called with mongodb - RUNNING
[2015-03-23 11:17:16,111][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] River mongodb startup pending
[2015-03-23 11:17:16,123][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Starting river mongodb
[2015-03-23 11:17:16,124][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB options: secondaryreadpreference [true], drop_collection [false], include_collection [], throttlesize [5000], gridfs [true], filter [null], db [test], collection [users], script [null], indexing to [mongotest]/[users]
[2015-03-23 11:17:16,129][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] GridFS Mapping: {"users":{"properties":{"content":{"type":"attachment"},"filename":{"type":"string"},"contentType":{"type":"string"},"md5":{"type":"string"},"length":{"type":"long"},"chunkSize":{"type":"long"}}}}
[2015-03-23 11:17:16,155][INFO ][river.mongodb ] [Sean Cassidy] Creating MongoClient for [[127.0.0.1:27017]]
[2015-03-23 11:17:18,907][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoConfigProvider] MongoDB version - 3.0.0
[2015-03-23 11:17:18,984][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.CollectionSlurper] MongoDBRiver is beginning initial import of test.users
[2015-03-23 11:17:19,502][INFO ][river.mongodb ] [Sean Cassidy] Creating MongoClient for [[MTRCW077:27017]]
[2015-03-23 11:17:19,512][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Started river mongodb
```